# limit page request with php

Tags: php

I have this code that prevents users from making multiple requests on a page and it records ip address in a text file along with a string of numbers i assume its a time stamp but im not sure looks like this `173.1.1.100 - Requested on: 1303521541`how do i change that to readable time with a date?

```
$ipLog='log.txt'; //Logfile
$timeout='1'; //Wait Time
$goHere=$headers; //Page To Access

$register_globals = (bool) ini_get('register_gobals');
if ($register_globals) $vis_ip = getenv(REMOTE_ADDR);
else $vis_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


function recordData($vis_ip,$ipLog,$goHere)
{ 
    $log=fopen("$ipLog", "a+"); 
    fputs ($log,$vis_ip." - Requested on: ".time()."\n"); 
    fclose($log); 

    //
    //
    //

    exit(0);
}

function checkLog($vis_ip,$ipLog,$timeout) 
{
    global $valid; $ip=$vis_ip;
    $data=file("$ipLog"); $now=time();

    foreach ($data as $record) 
    {
        $subdata=explode(" - Requested on: ",$record);
        if ($now < ($subdata[1]+600*$timeout) && $ip == $subdata[0]) 
        {
            $valid=0; echo "$timeout min wait.";
            break;
        }
    }
} 

checkLog($vis_ip,$ipLog,$timeout);
if ($valid!="0") recordData($vis_ip,$ipLog,$goHere);
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but if you have control over your PHP settings, do yourself a favor and check out http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When file has been saved, save a date

```
 fputs ($log,$vis_ip." - Requested on: ".date("Y-M-d H:m:s")."\n");
```

when its extracted , revert to timestamp and keep the logic

```
$subdata=explode(" - Requested on: ",$record);
$subdata[1]= strtotime($subdata[1]); //convert date to timestamp
```